# edit profile from frontend - symfony

Tags: php, symfony1

I have a website in symfony framework

I have a table sfGuardUserProfile in schema.yml, and registeration form seems to work fine.

Now i want users can edit their profile

how can I do that ?

thanks!

Comment: did you know how to create forms and save them?

Answer (score 1):

Start with the schema.yml, edit sfGuardUserProfile to add columns or change their definition. 
Your changes here will show up in the form.

As Hilgers says, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? This is a very open question.

Answer (score 0):

There's `BasesfGuardUserAdminForm` bundled with `sfGuardPlugin`. Configure it to fit as you wish.